# How to build React Native package in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I wanna build React Native iOS PhotoEditor module in Swift.

I simply created a new library using [react-native-create-library](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library) and modified the iOS module like this.

For now, I just wanna push a simple UIViewController.
I followed [Native Modules Guideline](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios) of React Native but I am getting error while launching the app.
I attached the screenshot of the structure, full codes and error logs.

[image: Screenshot]

```
//  RNPhotoEditor.swift
//  RNPhotoEditor
//
//  Created by Gang on 2/13/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Facebook. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc(RNPhotoEditor)
class RNPhotoEditor: NSObject {

    @objc func Edit(props: NSDictionary, onDone: RCTResponseSenderBlock, onCancel: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
        let editorVC = PhotoEditorViewController()
        getRootVC().present(editorVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func getRootVC() -> UIViewController {
        var root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

        while root?.presentedViewController != nil {
            root = root?.presentedViewController
        }

        return root!
    }
}


//
//  RNPhotoEditorBridge.m
//  RNPhotoEditor
//
//  Created by Gang on 2/13/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Facebook. All rights reserved.
//

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(RNPhotoEditor, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(Edit:(nonnull NSDictionary *)props onDone:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)onDone onCancel:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)onCancel)

@end


//
//  RNPhotoEditor-Bridging-Header.h
//  RNPhotoEditor-Bridging-Header
//
//  Created by Gang on 2/13/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Facebook. All rights reserved.
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

- Here is the error log.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ezczldbbkpyqcxaeyxheyjdtqbth/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React'
ld: warning: object file (/Users/gang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ezczldbbkpyqcxaeyxheyjdtqbth/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libLRDRCTSimpleToast.a(UIView+Toast.o)) was built for newer iOS version (9.3) than being linked (9.0)
ld: warning: object file (/Users/gang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ezczldbbkpyqcxaeyxheyjdtqbth/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libLRDRCTSimpleToast.a(LRDRCTSimpleToast.o)) was built for newer iOS version (9.3) than being linked (9.0)
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "value witness table for Builtin.UnknownObject", referenced from:
      full type metadata for RNPhotoEditor.PhotoEditorViewController in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      full type metadata for RNPhotoEditor.RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "(extension in Foundation):Swift.String._bridgeToObjectiveC() -> __C.NSString", referenced from:
      RNPhotoEditor.PhotoEditorViewController.init(nibName: Swift.String?, bundle: __C.NSBundle?) -> RNPhotoEditor.PhotoEditorViewController in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
  "static (extension in Foundation):Swift.String._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(__C.NSString?) -> Swift.String", referenced from:
      @objc RNPhotoEditor.PhotoEditorViewController.init(nibName: Swift.String?, bundle: __C.NSBundle?) -> RNPhotoEditor.PhotoEditorViewController in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
  "(extension in Foundation):Swift.Array._bridgeToObjectiveC() -> __C.NSArray", referenced from:
      reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned __C.NSArray?) -> () to @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed [Any]?) -> () in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "Swift._fatalErrorMessage(_: Swift.StaticString, _: Swift.StaticString, file: Swift.StaticString, line: Swift.UInt, flags: Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never", referenced from:
      RNPhotoEditor.RNPhotoEditor.getRootVC() -> __C.UIViewController in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "type metadata for Any", referenced from:
      reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned __C.NSArray?) -> () to @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed [Any]?) -> () in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreFoundation", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreFoundation_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreFoundation_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreFoundation_$_RNPhotoEditor)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics_$_RNPhotoEditor)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreImage", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreImage_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreImage_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreImage_$_RNPhotoEditor)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDarwin", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDarwin_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDarwin_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDarwin_$_RNPhotoEditor)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch_$_RNPhotoEditor)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation_$_RNPhotoEditor)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftMetal", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftMetal_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftMetal_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftMetal_$_RNPhotoEditor)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftObjectiveC", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftObjectiveC_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftObjectiveC_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftObjectiveC_$_RNPhotoEditor)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftQuartzCore", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftQuartzCore_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftQuartzCore_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftQuartzCore_$_RNPhotoEditor)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUIKit", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUIKit_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUIKit_$_RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUIKit_$_RNPhotoEditor)
  "_swift_allocObject", referenced from:
      @objc RNPhotoEditor.RNPhotoEditor.Edit(props: __C.NSDictionary, onDone: ([Any]?) -> (), onCancel: ([Any]?) -> ()) -> () in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "_swift_bridgeObjectRelease", referenced from:
      RNPhotoEditor.PhotoEditorViewController.init(nibName: Swift.String?, bundle: __C.NSBundle?) -> RNPhotoEditor.PhotoEditorViewController in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      outlined consume of Swift.String? in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned __C.NSArray?) -> () to @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed [Any]?) -> () in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "_swift_bridgeObjectRetain", referenced from:
      outlined copy of Swift.String? in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned __C.NSArray?) -> () to @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed [Any]?) -> () in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "_swift_deallocObject", referenced from:
      l_objectdestroy in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
      l_objectdestroy.2 in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "_swift_getInitializedObjCClass", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for RNPhotoEditor.PhotoEditorViewController in libRNPhotoEditor.a(PhotoEditorViewController.o)
      RNPhotoEditor.RNPhotoEditor.getRootVC() -> __C.UIViewController in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
      type metadata accessor for RNPhotoEditor.RNPhotoEditor in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "_swift_getObjCClassFromMetadata", referenced from:
      __C.UIViewController.__allocating_init() -> __C.UIViewController in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "_swift_isaMask", referenced from:
      RNPhotoEditor.RNPhotoEditor.Edit(props: __C.NSDictionary, onDone: ([Any]?) -> (), onCancel: ([Any]?) -> ()) -> () in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "_swift_release", referenced from:
      @objc RNPhotoEditor.RNPhotoEditor.Edit(props: __C.NSDictionary, onDone: ([Any]?) -> (), onCancel: ([Any]?) -> ()) -> () in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
  "_swift_retain", referenced from:
      @objc RNPhotoEditor.RNPhotoEditor.Edit(props: __C.NSDictionary, onDone: ([Any]?) -> (), onCancel: ([Any]?) -> ()) -> () in libRNPhotoEditor.a(RNPhotoEditor.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am really not sure what the following error means.

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64`

Also, how can I clear this kind of warnings?

`ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'`

Can someone please tell me how to write Swift iOS library for React Native? I am struggling for a couple of days but no luck.

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Did you link the static library (.a file) in "Link Binary with Libraries" ??

Comment: Of course, it's not link error

Comment: Does your library depend other .frameworks??

Comment: No, it's simple library to launch a UIViewController.

Comment: Can you verify what's in Framework Search Paths and Header Search Paths in Build Settings?

Comment: Hey man! Didi you solve it? How did you do? I have the same issue. Thanks!